# difference between elapsed time in matrix multiplication with and without using shared memory in cuda

Tags: cuda, elapsedtime, gpu-shared-memory

I am new in CUDA programming. My program is matrix multiplication with and without shared memory.  I use the codes in the `Cuda_C_Programming_Guide` ebook.  In the book we see the program which uses shared memory has less elapsed time than the elapsed time in the non-shared program. But when I run the programs it is the other way around. Does anyone know why? Or am I wrong?

non-shared memory :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/system_error.h>
#include <thrust/system/cuda_error.h>
#include <sstream>

typedef struct _Matrix
{
    int height;//number of rows
    int width;//number of columns
    float *elements;
}Matrix;


#define BLOCK_SIZE 20
__global__ void add_matrix_kernel(const Matrix a,const Matrix b,Matrix c)
{
    int N=a.width;
    int row=blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col=blockIdx.x * blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    c.elements[row * N + col]=a.elements[row * N + col]+b.elements[row * N + col];

}

__global__ void simpleMultiply(const Matrix a,const Matrix b, Matrix c)
{ 
    int N=a.width;
    int TILE_DIM=a.width;
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y; 
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; 
    int sum = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < TILE_DIM; i++) 
    { 
        sum += a.elements[row*TILE_DIM+i] * b.elements[i*N+col]; 
    } 
    c.elements[row*N+col] = sum; 
}

void add_matrix(const Matrix A,const Matrix B,Matrix C)
{

    // Load A and B to device memory
    Matrix d_A;
    Matrix d_B;
    Matrix d_C;

    d_A.width = A.width; d_A.height = A.height;
    d_B.width = B.width; d_B.height = B.height;
    d_C.width = C.width; d_C.height = C.height;



    size_t sizeA = A.width * A.height * sizeof(float);
    size_t sizeB = B.width * B.height * sizeof(float);
    size_t sizeC = C.width * C.height * sizeof(float);
    //allocate space for device copies of A,B,C 
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_A.elements, sizeA);
    //gpuErrchk( cudaMalloc(&a_d, size*sizeof(int)) );
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_B.elements, sizeB);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_C.elements, sizeC);
    //copy inputs to device
    cudaMemcpy(d_A.elements, A.elements, sizeA,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);     
    cudaMemcpy(d_B.elements, B.elements, sizeA,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


    dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE,BLOCK_SIZE);
    dim3 dimGrid(B.width/dimBlock.x, A.height/dimBlock.y);


    //add_matrix_kernel<<<grid_size,block_size>>>(d_A, d_B, d_C);

    simpleMultiply<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(d_A,d_B,d_C);

    // Read C from device memory
    cudaMemcpy(C.elements, d_C.elements, sizeA,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    // Free device memory
    cudaFree(d_A.elements);
    cudaFree(d_B.elements);
    cudaFree(d_C.elements);

}

//void print_matrix(int *c,int row,int col)
//{
//  for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i){
//      for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j)
//          printf("%d ",c[col*i+j]);
//      printf("\n\n");
//  }
//}

void print_matrix(Matrix A){
    printf("Matrix:\n");
    int i;
    int rows=0;
    //printf("row %d\n",rows);
    for(i=0; i<A.width*A.height; i++){
        if(i%A.width==0){ printf("\n");printf("row %d\n",rows);rows++;}
        printf("%6.4f\t",A.elements[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

}

void throw_on_cuda_error(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line)
{
    if(code != cudaSuccess)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << file << "(" << line << ")";
        std::string file_and_line;
        ss >> file_and_line;
        throw thrust::system_error(code, thrust::cuda_category(), file_and_line);
    }
}

int main()
{
    cudaEvent_t start,stop;
    try{
        int i,j;
        Matrix A,B;
        Matrix C;

        A.width=1200;
        A.height=1200;
        B.width=1200;
        B.height=1200;
        C.width=B.width;
        C.height=A.height;
        size_t sizeA = A.width * A.height * sizeof(float);
        A.elements = (float *)malloc(sizeA);
        //random_init(A.elements,A.width * A.height );
        size_t sizeB = B.width * B.height * sizeof(float);
        B.elements= (float *)malloc(sizeB);
        //random_init(B.elements,B.width * B.height);
        size_t sizeC = C.width * C.height * sizeof(float);
        C.elements= (float *)malloc(sizeC);
        for(i=0;i<A.width*A.height;i++)
            A.elements[i]=1;

        for(int i=0;i<B.width*B.height;i++)
            B.elements[i]=1;
        printf("matrix A(%d,%d) & matrix B(%d,%d) & matrix C(%d,%d)\n",A.height,A.width,B.height,B.width,C.height,C.width);
        cudaEventCreate(&start);
        cudaEventCreate(&stop);
        cudaEventRecord(start,0);

        add_matrix(A,B,C);
        cudaPeekAtLastError() ;
        cudaDeviceSynchronize() ;
        cudaEventRecord(stop,0);
        cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
        float elapsedTime;
        cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime,start,stop);

        printf("Time to genreat : %3.5f ms\n",elapsedTime);
        cudaEventDestroy(start);
        cudaEventDestroy(stop);

        /*printf("\nA\n");
        print_matrix(A.elements,A.height,A.width);
        printf("\nB\n");
        print_matrix(B.elements,B.height,B.width);*/
        printf("\nC\n");
        //      print_matrix(C.elements,C.height,C.width);
        //  print_matrix(C);
        printf("C[%d] = %f\n",0,C.elements[0]);
        printf("C[%d] = %f\n",(C.width)-1,C.elements[(C.width)-1]);
        printf("C[%d] = %f\n",(C.width)*(C.height)-1,C.elements[(C.width)*(C.height)-1]);
        free(A.elements);
        free(B.elements);
        free(C.elements);
        getchar();
        throw_on_cuda_error(cudaSetDevice(-1), __FILE__, __LINE__);
    }
    catch(thrust::system_error &e)
    {
        std::cerr << "CUDA error after cudaSetDevice: " << e.what() << std::endl;

        // oops, recover
        cudaSetDevice(0);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Using shared memory:

```
// Matrices are stored in row-major order:
// M(row, col) = *(M.elements + row * M.stride + col)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/system_error.h>
#include <thrust/system/cuda_error.h>
#include <sstream>

#define BLOCK_SIZE 20

typedef struct {
    int width;
    int height;
    int stride; 
    float* elements;
} Matrix;

// Get a matrix element
__device__ float GetElement(const Matrix A, int row, int col)
{
    return A.elements[row * A.stride + col];
}

// Set a matrix element
__device__ void SetElement(Matrix A, int row, int col,
    float value)
{
    A.elements[row * A.stride + col] = value;
}

// Get the BLOCK_SIZExBLOCK_SIZE sub-matrix Asub of A that is
// located col sub-matrices to the right and row sub-matrices down
// from the upper-left corner of A

__device__ Matrix GetSubMatrix(Matrix A, int row, int col)
{
    Matrix Asub;

    Asub.width = BLOCK_SIZE;
    Asub.height = BLOCK_SIZE;
    Asub.stride = A.stride;
    Asub.elements = &A.elements[A.stride * BLOCK_SIZE * row+ BLOCK_SIZE * col];
    return Asub;
}

// Thread block size
// Forward declaration of the matrix multiplication kernel
__global__ void MatMulKernel(const Matrix, const Matrix, Matrix);

// Matrix multiplication - Host code
// Matrix dimensions are assumed to be multiples of BLOCK_SIZE
void MatMul(const Matrix A, const Matrix B, Matrix C)
{
    // Load A and B to device memory
    Matrix d_A;
    d_A.width = d_A.stride = A.width; d_A.height = A.height;
    size_t size = A.width * A.height * sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc(&d_A.elements, size);
    cudaMemcpy(d_A.elements, A.elements, size,
        cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    Matrix d_B;
    d_B.width = d_B.stride = B.width; d_B.height = B.height;
    size = B.width * B.height * sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc(&d_B.elements, size);
    cudaMemcpy(d_B.elements, B.elements, size,
        cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    // Allocate C in device memory
    Matrix d_C;
    d_C.width = d_C.stride = C.width; d_C.height = C.height;
    size = C.width * C.height * sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc(&d_C.elements, size);
    // Invoke kernel
    dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE,BLOCK_SIZE);
    //dim3 dimBlock(C.height, C.width);
    dim3 dimGrid(B.width / dimBlock.x, A.height / dimBlock.y);
    //dim3 dimGrid((B.width+dimBlock.x-1) / dimBlock.x, (A.height+dimBlock.y-1) / dimBlock.y);

    MatMulKernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_A, d_B, d_C);

    // Read C from device memory
    cudaMemcpy(C.elements, d_C.elements, size,
        cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    // Free device memory
    cudaFree(d_A.elements);
    cudaFree(d_B.elements);
    cudaFree(d_C.elements);
}

// Matrix multiplication kernel called by MatMul()
__global__ void MatMulKernel(Matrix A, Matrix B, Matrix C)
{
    // Block row and column
    int blockRow = blockIdx.y;
    int blockCol = blockIdx.x;
    // Each thread block computes one sub-matrix Csub of C
    Matrix Csub = GetSubMatrix(C, blockRow, blockCol);
    // Each thread computes one element of Csub
    // by accumulating results into Cvalue
    float Cvalue = 0;
    // Thread row and column within Csub
    int row = threadIdx.y;
    int col = threadIdx.x;
    // Loop over all the sub-matrices of A and B that are
    // required to compute Csub
    // Multiply each pair of sub-matrices together
    // and accumulate the results
    for (int m = 0; m < (A.width / BLOCK_SIZE); ++m) {
        // Get sub-matrix Asub of A
        Matrix Asub = GetSubMatrix(A, blockRow, m);
        // Get sub-matrix Bsub of B
        Matrix Bsub = GetSubMatrix(B, m, blockCol);
        // Shared memory used to store Asub and Bsub respectively
        __shared__ float As[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];
        __shared__ float Bs[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];
        // Load Asub and Bsub from device memory to shared memory
        // Each thread loads one element of each sub-matrix
        As[row][col] = GetElement(Asub, row, col);
        Bs[row][col] = GetElement(Bsub, row, col);
        // Synchronize to make sure the sub-matrices are loaded
        // before starting the computation
        __syncthreads();
        // Multiply Asub and Bsub together
        for (int e = 0; e < BLOCK_SIZE; ++e)
            Cvalue += As[row][e] * Bs[e][col];
        // Synchronize to make sure that the preceding
        // computation is done before loading two new
        // sub-matrices of A and B in the next iteration
        __syncthreads();
    }
    // Write Csub to device memory
    // Each thread writes one element
    SetElement(Csub, row, col, Cvalue);
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// print_matrix function ///////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void print_matrix(float *c,int row,int col){
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j)
            printf("%f ",c[col*i +j]);
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// random_init function ///////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void random_init(float *a,int size){
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        a[i]=rand()%10;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void throw_on_cuda_error(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line)
{
    if(code != cudaSuccess)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << file << "(" << line << ")";
        std::string file_and_line;
        ss >> file_and_line;
        throw thrust::system_error(code, thrust::cuda_category(), file_and_line);
    }
}

int main(void){
    cudaEvent_t start,stop;
    try
    {
        Matrix A,B,C;
        A.width=1200;
        A.height=1200;/////
        B.width=1200;/////
        B.height=1200;
        C.width=B.width;
        C.height=A.height;

        size_t size = A.width * A.height * sizeof(float);
        A.elements = (float *)malloc(size);
        //random_init(A.elements,A.width * A.height );
        size = B.width * B.height * sizeof(float);
        B.elements= (float *)malloc(size);
        //random_init(B.elements,B.width * B.height);
        size = C.width * C.height * sizeof(float);
        C.elements= (float *)malloc(size);
        for(int i=0;i<A.width*A.height;i++)
            A.elements[i]=1;
        for(int i=0;i<B.width*B.height;i++)
            B.elements[i]=1;
        printf("matrix A(%d,%d) & matrix B(%d,%d) & matrix C(%d,%d)\n",A.width,A.height,B.width,
               B.height,C.width,C.height);
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////\|/
        cudaEventCreate(&start);
        cudaEventCreate(&stop);
        cudaEventRecord(start,0);
        MatMul(A,B,C);
        cudaPeekAtLastError() ;
        cudaDeviceSynchronize() ;
        cudaEventRecord(stop,0);
        cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
        float elapsedTime;
        cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime,start,stop);
        printf("Time to genreat : %4.5f ms\n",elapsedTime);
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////\|/
        printf("%s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));
        //printf("\nA\n");
        //print_matrix(A.elements,A.height,A.width);
        //printf("\nB\n");
        //print_matrix(B.elements,B.height,B.width);
        printf("\nC\n");
        //print_matrix(C.elements,C.height,C.width);


        printf("C[%d]=%f\n",0,C.elements[0]);
        printf("C[%d]=%f\n",C.width -1,C.elements[C.width-1]);
        printf("C[%d]=%f\n",(C.width * C.height)-1,C.elements[(C.width * C.height)-1]);

        getchar();
        throw_on_cuda_error(cudaSetDevice(-1), __FILE__, __LINE__);
    }
    catch(thrust::system_error &e)
    {
        std::cerr << "CUDA error after cudaSetDevice: " << e.what() << std::endl;

        // oops, recover
        cudaSetDevice(0);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

The debug build gives the following output:

```
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'E:\FarnAz\Cuda Project\Projects\GPU_Matrix\Debug\GPU_Matrix.exe', Symbols loaded.
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.2\bin\cudart32_42_9.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvcuda.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nsi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\Wincert\win32cert.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvinit.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\detoured.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\Nvd3d9wrap.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\nvdxgiwrap.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Unloaded 'C:\ProgramData\Wincert\win32cert.dll'
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1214) has exited with code 1849301074 (0x6e3a1852).
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wintrust.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'GPU_Matrix.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
```

E.g. the result for matrices `1000*1000` is about 1219 ms for the non-shared code and about 1770 ms for the shared memory code.

When I build in release mode, the program doesn't build successfully and shows some errors in error list. But I don't know why!
The output in release mode is:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: GPU_Matrix, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>Build started 11/13/2013 10:39:47 AM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Release\GPU_Matrix.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>AddCudaCompilePropsDeps:
1>Skipping target "AddCudaCompilePropsDeps" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
1>CudaBuild:
1>  Compiling CUDA source file main.cu...
1>  
1>  E:\FarnAz\Cuda Project\Projects\GPU_Matrix\GPU_Matrix>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.2\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2010 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin"  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.2\include"    --keep-dir "Release" -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile      -Xcompiler "/EHsc /nologo /Od /Zi  /MD  " -o "Release\main.cu.obj" "E:\FarnAz\Cuda Project\Projects\GPU_Matrix\GPU_Matrix\main.cu" 
1>  main.cu
1>  tmpxft_00001c70_00000000-0_main.cudafe1.gpu
1>  tmpxft_00001c70_00000000-5_main.cudafe2.gpu
1>  main.cu
1>  tmpxft_00001c70_00000000-0_main.cudafe1.cpp
1>  tmpxft_00001c70_00000000-11_main.ii
1>main.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cudaFree@4
1>main.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cudaConfigureCall@32
1>main.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cudaMemcpy@16
1>main.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cudaMalloc@8
1>main.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cudaGetErrorString@4
1>main.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cudaSetDevice@4
1>main.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cudaEventDestroy@4
1>main.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cudaEventElapsedTime@12
1>main.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cudaEventSynchronize@4
1>main.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cudaDeviceSynchronize@0
1>main.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cudaPeekAtLastError@0
1>main.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cudaEventRecord@8
1>main.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cudaEventCreate@4
1>main.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cudaSetupArgument@12
1>main.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___cudaRegisterFunction@40
1>main.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___cudaRegisterFatBinary@4
1>main.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___cudaUnregisterFatBinary@4
1>main.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cudaLaunch@4
1>E:\FarnAz\Cuda Project\Projects\GPU_Matrix\Release\GPU_Matrix.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 18 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:08.43
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I ran `vectorAdd` in both modes. Then I pasted my code in that project. In debug mode it has no problem and the result in non-shared is about 1372 ms and in shared memory is about 1842 ms. But in release mode it shows a new window that tells :

```
Debugging information for ‘vectorAdd.exe’ cannot be found or does not match. Binary was not built with debug information. Do you want to continue debugging ?
```

When I click `yes` it continues and runs with no error. And the result in non-shared is about 645 ms and in shared-memory is about 183 ms. I don’t understand why the results are vice versa in release mode and which one is true? Is the result in release mode true for every project or in debug mode?

Comment: You are not indicating which architecture you are considering. Using shared memory does not necessarily reduces the processing time, and this much depends on the GPU architecture. Since Fermi on, shared memory can be seen as a "controlled cache" and for some algorithm the L1 caching mechanism could be already enough to have data loaded from global memory reside on-chip close to the processing cores. But even these same statements could be not enough  to exaplain what it's going on in your case, as I haven't tested the code at hand on different architectures. Take this comment just as a remark.

Comment: thanks for your answer, and I forgot to say I use windows 7 ultimate 64bit and GeForce GT555M and visual studio 2010.

Comment: The GeForce GT555M belongs to the Fermi generation.

Comment: Please provide the complete codes you are comparing, as well as the actual results output in your case.  We don't all have access to that particular book.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I think that the "ebook" the poster is mentioning is the CUDA C Programming Guide and the example he is referring is that in Section 3.2.3. I'm just interpreting his post since I would not say that the guide is neither an ebook nor a book.

Comment: I added complete codes.

Comment: When I run your codes on a Quadro5000 (a Fermi device) I get about 40ms for the shared memory code and about 90ms for the non-shared-memory code.  Are you compiling a debug or release project in visual studio?  Please provide your actual results and the complete compile command you are using in visual studio (it will be displayed in the output window at the bottom while the program is compiling.)  If I compile with the `-G` switch, I see that the program behavior is reversed, and the shared memory version takes longer to execute.

Comment: I have the same behavior on a GeForce GT540M, compiled in release mode.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I compile the debug project and provided the result in edited post.

Comment: Please switch to compiling the project for Release mode instead of Debug mode, and re-run the comparison.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I compiled the release project and provided the result in edited post.

Comment: Obviously your project configuration for release is messed up.  My suggestion would be to switch to building one of the cuda samples like `vectorAdd` and make sure you can build and run that properly in both debug and release mode first.    Then take your code, and replace the vector add project code with your code, and build and run it that way. That will avoid having to go through all your project settings to figure out why it isn't linking correctly.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I ran vectorAdd in both mode as you said and I wrote the result in edited post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this message:

> “Debugging information for ‘vectorAdd.exe’ cannot be found or does not match. Binary was not built with debug information. Do you want to continue debugging ?” ,

Because of the way you are starting the executable in Visual Studio.  When you build the release project you should just run it, rather than "start debugging".  You'll need to explore visual studio a bit more.

The results you get seem correct in Release mode.  The shared memory code runs faster, as expected.  When building a "Debug" project in visual studio, the `-G` switch will normally get passed to the `nvcc` compiler driver which has a significant affect on code generation.  It does more than just allow for debugging by adding symbols.  It disables many optimizations that the compiler might make, so as to make source debugging easier.

You should not evaluate CUDA code performance in "Debug" mode or by passing the `-G` switch to `nvcc`.

Comment: Really so much thanks for your answer. Yes I didn't know that I should  link the cudart.lib to my release project again. now my project runs successfully.